# awaiting a httpsCallable when calling it in the frontend doesn't seem to work

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, google-cloud-functions

I am using cloud functions and I have httpsCallable that adds a message to a firestore database which am awaiting when calling it in the frontend. The problem is that when I do this, the result gets resolved way later after the function where it's been defined is called. Am not sure if this is an async/await problem or a cloud function httpsCallable's problem. Thanks in advance

Here's the code in the backend:

```js
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions
// and setup triggers.
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();


// Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});


// Take the text parameter passed to this HTTP endpoint and insert it into 
// Firestore under the path /messages/:documentId/original
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    // Grab the text parameter.
    const original = req.query.text;
    // Push the new message into Firestore using the Firebase Admin SDK.
    const writeResult = await admin.firestore().collection('messages').add({original: original});
    // Send back a message that we've successfully written the message
    res.json({result: `Message with ID: ${writeResult.id} added.`});
  });

// a callable version of addMessage
  exports.addMessageCallable = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    // ...
    const original = data.text;
    // Push the new message into Firestore using the Firebase Admin SDK.
    const writeResult = await admin.firestore().collection('messages').add({original: original});
    console.log("********** writeResult **********", writeResult.id)
    // Send back a message that we've successfully written the message
    return {
      "success": true,
      "message": data.text,
      "documentId": writeResult.id
    }
  });


  // Listens for new messages added to /messages/:documentId/original and creates an
// uppercase version of the message to /messages/:documentId/uppercase
exports.makeUppercase = functions.firestore.document('/messages/{documentId}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
  // Grab the current value of what was written to Firestore.
  const original = snap.data().original;

  // Access the parameter `{documentId}` with `context.params`
  functions.logger.log('Uppercasing', context.params.documentId, original);
  
  const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
  
  // You must return a Promise when performing asynchronous tasks inside a Functions such as
  // writing to Firestore.
  // Setting an 'uppercase' field in Firestore document returns a Promise.
  return snap.ref.set({uppercase}, {merge: true});
});
```

Then in the frontend:

```js
import './App.css';
import firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/functions";


// values being read from a .emv
const { REACT_APP_FB_API_KEY, REACT_APP_FB_AUTH_DOMAIN, REACT_APP_FB_PROJECTID, REACT_APP_FB_STORAGE_BUCKET,REACT_APP_FB_MSG_SENDER_ID, REACT_APP_FB_APP_ID, REACT_APP_FB_MEASUREMENT_ID } = process.env;

// initialize the SDK
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: REACT_APP_FB_API_KEY,
  authDomain: REACT_APP_FB_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: REACT_APP_FB_PROJECTID,
  storageBucket: REACT_APP_FB_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: REACT_APP_FB_MSG_SENDER_ID,
  appId: REACT_APP_FB_APP_ID,
  measurementId: REACT_APP_FB_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Cloud Functions through Firebase
const functions = firebase.functions();

function App() {

  const sampleFunc1 = () => {
    console.log("**** 2 ******")
    // calls sampleFunc1
    sampleFunc2();
  };

  const sampleFunc2 = () => {
    console.log("**** 3 ******")
    // calls addMsgFunc
    addMsgFunc();
  };

  const addMsgFunc = async () => {
    console.log("**** 4 ******")
    const addMessage = functions.httpsCallable('addMessageCallable');
    try {
      console.log("**** 5: before result ******")
      const result = await addMessage({ text: "working!!" });
      console.log("********* 6. result ******", result.data)
      console.log("**** 7: after result ******")
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("**** err: *****", error)
    }
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log("**** 1 ******")
    sampleFunc1()
    console.log("**** 8. done ******")
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <h3>hello world!</h3>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>click me</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;




// here's the result that I get

// **** 1 ******
// **** 2 ******
// **** 3 ******
// **** 4 ******
// **** 5: before result ******
// **** 8. done ******
// ********* 6. result ******
// **** 7: after result ******

// What I actually want

// **** 1 ******
// **** 2 ******
// **** 3 ******
// **** 4 ******
// **** 5: before result ******
// ********* 6. result ******
// **** 7: after result ******
// **** 8. done ******
```

You can find the entire code in [this github repo](https://github.com/kd-kinuthiadavid/sample-CF-app)

Comment: Can you show the **entire** code of your Cloud Function (i.e. the content of the `index.js` file)? "I have httpsCallable that sets custom claims" => The CF code you show does not set any custom claim and actually is not asynchronous.  Again we need to see the exact code, in order to be able to help you. Also, how do you define `functions`in your front end? Finally, do you get any error?

Comment: @Renaud Tarnec, what do you mean by "how do you define `functions` in your front end?"? - I am using react but the above functions are in a module and not a component. Also, I don't get any errors. As for the setting of custom claims, I don't have a problem with that, the problem is that calling `updateAdminClaims` seems to be skipped and later code is executed

Comment: You are only showing pieces of code. It is very hard (if not impossible) for us to help you under these conditions. You need to share the entire code of your Cloud Functions and clearly show how all imports and calls are linked in the front end. There are many areas where we could find a potential error, not only the "areas" you are sharing. Also did you note that you call `httpsCallable("customClaims-setAuthCustomClaims");`but your CF seems to be declared with `setAuthCustomClaims`.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec, I've edited the question to show the entire code and also shared a link to a reproducible project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `await` the parent functions as well because they are `async` (or returning promises) else the function will continue working on part 8 without awaiting part 6,7.

```
function App() {

  const sampleFunc1 = async () => {
    console.log("**** 2 ******")
    // calls sampleFunc1
    await sampleFunc2();
  };

  const sampleFunc2 = async () => {
    console.log("**** 3 ******")
    // calls addMsgFunc
    await addMsgFunc();
  };

  const addMsgFunc = async () => {
    console.log("**** 4 ******")
    const addMessage = functions.httpsCallable('addMessageCallable');
    try {
      console.log("**** 5: before result ******")
      const result = await addMessage({ text: "working!!" });
      console.log("********* 6. result ******", result.data)
      console.log("**** 7: after result ******")
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("**** err: *****", error)
    }
  };

  const handleClick = async () => {
    console.log("**** 1 ******")
    await sampleFunc1()
    console.log("**** 8. done ******")
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <h3>hello world!</h3>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>click me</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The `addMsgFunc` function was async but you were not using await when calling that in `sampleFunc2`. I've also made sample functions async. Let me know if that still doesn't work.

Comment: yup, awaiting the parent functions did the trick, thanks @dharmaraj